# Applink cannot resolve the type Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I Have imported the facebook sdk into my workspace and added to my project i'm getting this error...

please help me..[image]

Comment: Can you update to the 3.15 SDK that was just released yesterday?  We put some fixes in for linking errors.  Also can you describe your situation a little more, windows, mac, android studio, intellij, something else?  Thanks.

Comment: yeah that just worked after updating the SDK. thanks for the comment :)